# System V message queue periodically reseted for some reason

Tags: c, linux

I'm studying IPC and have a basic example of System V message queue usage. Code is pretty simple: main process creates massage queue then fork() and starts sending messages in endless loop with some delay. Child process receive messages in a loop with logic: sleep - receive all accumulated - sleep.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


typedef struct 
{
    int value;
} messageText;

typedef struct 
{
    long mtype;
    messageText mtext;
} queueMessage;


int main()
{ 
    key_t queueKey = ftok(__FILE__, 'M');
    int msgQueue = msgget(queueKey, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (0 == pid)
    {        
        // never returns
        child_main(msgQueue);
        abort();
    }

    queueMessage msg = 
    {
        .mtype = 1,
        .mtext = { 0 }
    };

    for (int i = 0; /* void */ ; ++i)
    {
        msg.mtext.value = i;

        int rc = msgsnd(msgQueue, &msg, sizeof(msg.mtext), 0);
        if (rc == -1)
            perror("msgsnd");

        usleep(250000);  // 0.25 sec

        struct msqid_ds queueInfo;
        msgctl(msgQueue, IPC_STAT, &queueInfo);
        printf("Messages in queue = %ld\n", queueInfo.msg_qnum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
void child_main(int msgQueue)
{
    queueMessage msg = { 0 };
    int msgTyp = 0;  // 1st message in queue
    int msgRcvFlg = IPC_NOWAIT | MSG_NOERROR;

    while (1)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            int rc = msgrcv(msgQueue, &msg, sizeof(msg.mtext), msgTyp, msgRcvFlg);
            if (-1 == rc)
            {
                if (errno == ENOMSG)
                {
                    goto sleep;
                }
                else
                {
                    perror("msgrcv");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            printf("read: %d\n", msg.mtext.value);
        }

    sleep:

        usleep(5000000);  // 5 sec.
    }
}
```

So the expected behavior is that parent messages accumulate in the queue until child wakes up, reads them and sleep() again. To see if it is the correct logic, I print messages number every time parent send new message. But the actual behavior is that queue content seems to be reseted for some reason so just few messages are received by child. The longer parent sleeps the less
messages are still in queue when child tries to receive them.

This is an example of output for parent sleeping for
0.25 sec.

```
Messages in queue = 1
Messages in queue = 2
Messages in queue = 3
Messages in queue = 4
Messages in queue = 5
Messages in queue = 0
Messages in queue = 1
Messages in queue = 2
Messages in queue = 3
read: 8
read: 9
read: 10
read: 11
Messages in queue = 0
Messages in queue = 1
Messages in queue = 0
...
```

`ipcs -l` output

```
------ Messages Limits --------
max queues system wide = 32000
max size of message (bytes) = 8192
default max size of queue (bytes) = 16384

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 18014398509465599
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 18446744073709551612
min seg size (bytes) = 1

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 32000
max semaphores per array = 32000
max semaphores system wide = 1024000000
max ops per semop call = 500
semaphore max value = 32767
```

I've found nothing about such a behavior in man pages. Could someone explain it, please?

Comment: Add an `_exit(127);` or `abort();` call after the call to `child_main`, just to make sure the child doesn't execute any parent code.

Comment: What is a `queueMessage`? Please ensure you are posting a [mre], and join your snippets if they form a single file. What does [`ipcs -l`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcs.1.html) tell you?

Comment: Use `key_t` and `pid_t`, without `__`. The other ones are undocumented implementation detail.

Comment: After each call to `printf(...)`, add an `fflush(stdout);` so that you get each log line as soon as possible.

Comment: Check the return value of all system calls and library functions, including `msgctl(...)`.

Comment: Add a `printf(...);` + `fflush(stdout);` after the `msgsnd(...)` call.

Comment: Post the full output on stdout, do not crop.

Comment: @Oka my bad, sorry about types. Edited. Output is also added to the question cause it's too large to post it here.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Now admittedly I'm on a macOS machine currently, but I cannot reproduce the described behaviour (this appear to 'work'). I would suggest following the previous advice of checking the return value of `msgctl`. Additionally, `queueInfo.msg_qnum` is of type `msgqnum_t`, which is simply an [*unsigned type at least as large as `unsigned short`*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysmsg.h.html). The uncertainty of this type means you should explicitly cast it (perhaps to `(unsigned long)`, use `%lu`) when passing it to `printf` to assuredly avoid UB from incorrectly typed varargs.

Comment: Also unable to reproduce on Linux. In addition to the previous advice, double check your terminal driver - try a different one, or write to a file instead. Note that `usleep` is deprecated. Consider adding more specific information about your system.

Comment: @Oka I'd had all of return values checking and removed them just to make code here shorter. Maybe I'm wrong about it, but I made sure that result is the same before writeng the question. I turned VM off three days ago and did nothing untill now. Now I also can't reproduce the problem and all modifications I've made to investigate the problem are working perfectly now. Wierd. But thank you for attempts to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the evidence that the issue could not be reproduced after a system reboot I would hazard a guess that the problem was facilitated by *orphaned processes* consuming messages from the same, stale message queue.

`msgget(queueKey, IPC_CREAT | 0660);` only creates a *new* message queue if there is not one already associated with the given key. Otherwise it quietly returns the previously created message queue.

`IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL` must be specified in the flags for `msgget` to fail (setting `errno` to `EEXIST`) when there is already a message queue associated with the given key.

There is nothing in the example that cleans up the message queue. This is done with:

```
int rc = msgctl(key, IPC_RMID, NULL);
```

Without this, System V message queues persist for the duration of the system's uptime (unless removed manually by `ipcrm`).

Additionally, the deterministic nature of `ftok`, and its relatively small address space, means there is the slight (but not impossible) chance that a different process was acquiring the same `key_t` via a collision, and consuming messages from the message queue.

Both possible problems can be partially addressed by using `IPC_PRIVATE` as the key for `msgget` (processes with the correct permissions can still manually specify a *msqid* to interact with when using `msgsnd` / `msgrcv`).

The general advice is to ensure you are cleaning up resources when you are done with them. This means *reaping* child processes properly, deleting message queues (shared memory and semaphores, too!) when they are no longer required, and of course checking all system calls.

Comment: Thank you for answer, the orphan process is the real cause. In addition to your note about `ftok` usage I have to say that my problem was also in careless `__pathname` and `__proj_id` args usage. It might lead to almost the same problem as in my question if I run the executable twice. No orphans but two processes have the same `ftok` result and as a result two parents write and two children read from the same queue.